# I search for an equivalent of Windows msg.exe in Linux C or C++

Tags: c++, c, linux, class

I searched via google, but I found nothing.

I search a sourcecode or a class for linux in C or C++ that allows  to send a message by a popup to a Win7 PC like msg.exe.

Comment: There is no universal solution for Linux. Have a look at QT or GTK libraries, but there are many others.

Comment: Are you looking to send a message from a linux machine to a Win7 PC, such that a popup appears on the PC? Wouldn't that need a client on the PC, at least?

Comment: Oh, right, i think i misunderstood the question

Comment: @Floris: The functionality is already built into Windows. There's no need for a client. (But I think it's turned off by default.)

Comment: @duskwuff - can you post a link referencing this functionality (and the API)? Presumably this will give OP the right search terms to figure it out...

Comment: @Floris: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/net_send.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make a popup, you need to reference a system-dependent program that interfaces with your window manager. Using msg.exe for windows works, because its a built-in program that makes popup boxes. If you're running ubuntu, try using xmessage, or notify-send (for built-in programs), otherwise you'll need to import a library that handles GUIs, like GTK+.

Answer (score 2):

The question is indeed a little misleading. If you want to send a message over the network, you should try smbclient. I'm not sure if it still works with Win7 but you're able to send messages from a linux box to windows with smbclient -M "my message".

Doing this in C or C++ is more complicated though. Maybe a look at the sourcecode of smbclient might help you.

Comment: Here is my problem, the smb-stuff works with WinXP but with Win7 dont't.

Comment: you're right. net send was used a lot in malicious ways and hence removed from vista onward. msg.exe is not compatible with smb-client and will probably never be. Depending on your use case something like a chat-server (jabber e.g.) or a simple TCP chat server with some gui might suffice (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html)